# add \n every certain character or 70 width characters in R

Tags: r

I have a modelA, and I want to insert enter keys one part for every ; and the other part is for after 70 width of the characters. I used "stri_wrap" function to do it but not perfect yet. Can anyone help me how to develop the code? I have my modelA and code for stri_wrap that I used are below. Thank you for advance.

```
modelA <- "f1_1 by v1_1 v2_1 (1-2) ; f1_9 by v1_9 v2_9 (1-2) ; f1_21 by v1_21 v2_21 (1-2) ; f1_31 by 
v1_31 v2_31 (1-2) ; f1_43 by v1_43 v2_43 (1-2) ; f1_53 by v1_53 v2_53 (1-2) ; f1_67 by v1_67 v2_67 
(1-2) ; f1_77 by v1_77 v2_77 (1-2) ; f1_105 by v1_105 v2_105 (1-2) ; f1_147 by v1_147 v2_147 (1-2) ; 
f1_196 by v1_196 v2_196 (1-2) ; f1_238 by v1_238 v2_238 (1-2) ; f1_280 by v1_280 v2_280 (1-2) ; 
f1_322 by v1_322 v2_322 (1-2) ; 
[v1_1@0 v1_9@0 v1_21@0 v1_31@0 v1_43@0 v1_53@0 v1_67@0 v1_77@0 v1_105@0 v1_147@0 v1_196@0 v1_238@0 v1_280@0 v1_322@0]; 
[f1_1 f1_9 f1_21 f1_31 f1_43 f1_53 f1_67 f1_77 f1_105 f1_147 f1_196 f1_238 f1_280 f1_322];"

if(nchar(modelA)>70){
  modelA <- stri_wrap(modelA,width=70,simplify = TRUE)
  modelA <- paste(modelA,collapse ="\n ")
}
```

I want the modelA to look like this;

```
modelA <- "f1_1 by v1_1 v2_1 (1-2) ; 
 f1_9 by v1_9 v2_9 (1-2) ; 
 f1_21 by v1_21 v2_21 (1-2) ; 
 f1_31 by v1_31 v2_31 (1-2) ; 
 f1_43 by v1_43 v2_43 (1-2) ; 
 f1_53 by v1_53 v2_53 (1-2) ; 
 f1_67 by v1_67 v2_67 (1-2) ;
 f1_77 by v1_77 v2_77 (1-2) ; 
 f1_105 by v1_105 v2_105 (1-2) ; 
 f1_147 by v1_147 v2_147 (1-2) ; 
 f1_196 by v1_196 v2_196 (1-2) ; 
 f1_238 by v1_238 v2_238 (1-2) ; 
 f1_280 by v1_280 v2_280 (1-2) ; 
 f1_322 by v1_322 v2_322 (1-2) ; 

 [v1_1@0 v1_9@0 v1_21@0 v1_31@0 v1_43@0 v1_53@0 v1_67@0 v1_77@0 v1_105@0 
 v1_147@0 v1_196@0 v1_238@0 v1_280@0 v1_322@0]; 
 [f1_1 f1_9 f1_21 f1_31 f1_43 f1_53 f1_67 f1_77 f1_105 f1_147 f1_196 
 f1_238 f1_280 f1_322];"
```

or

```
modelA <- "f1_1 by v1_1 v2_1 (1-2) ; f1_9 by v1_9 v2_9 (1-2) ; f1_21 by v1_21 v2_21 (1-2) ; 
 f1_31 by v1_31 v2_31 (1-2) ; f1_43 by v1_43 v2_43 (1-2) ; f1_53 by v1_53 v2_53 (1-2) ; 
 f1_67 by v1_67 v2_67 (1-2) ; f1_77 by v1_77 v2_77 (1-2) ; f1_105 by v1_105 v2_105 (1-2) ; 
 f1_147 by v1_147 v2_147 (1-2) ; f1_196 by v1_196 v2_196 (1-2) ; f1_238 by v1_238 v2_238 (1-2) ; 
 f1_280 by v1_280 v2_280 (1-2) ; f1_322 by v1_322 v2_322 (1-2) ; 

 [v1_1@0 v1_9@0 v1_21@0 v1_31@0 v1_43@0 v1_53@0 v1_67@0 v1_77@0 v1_105@0 
 v1_147@0 v1_196@0 v1_238@0 v1_280@0 v1_322@0]; 
 [f1_1 f1_9 f1_21 f1_31 f1_43 f1_53 f1_67 f1_77 f1_105 f1_147 f1_196 
 f1_238 f1_280 f1_322];"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply` on `str_wrap` after splitting by new lines added after the semicolons:

```r
str_list <- strsplit(gsub(";", ";\n", gsub("\n", "", modelA)), "\n")
modelA <- paste0(sapply(str_list, stringr::str_wrap, width = 70), collapse = "\n")
```

So now `modelA` looks like this:

```
modelA
#> [1] "f1_1 by v1_1 v2_1 (1-2) ;\nf1_9 by v1_9 v2_9 (1-2) ;\nf1_21 by v1_21 v2_21 (1-2) ;\nf1_31 by v1_31 v2_31 (1-2) ;\nf1_43 by v1_43 v2_43 (1-2) ;\nf1_53 by v1_53 v2_53 (1-2) ;\nf1_67 by v1_67 v2_67 (1-2) ;\nf1_77 by v1_77 v2_77 (1-2) ;\nf1_105 by v1_105 v2_105 (1-2) ;\nf1_147 by v1_147 v2_147 (1-2) ;\nf1_196 by v1_196 v2_196 (1-2) ;\nf1_238 by v1_238 v2_238 (1-2) ;\nf1_280 by v1_280 v2_280 (1-2) ;\nf1_322 by v1_322 v2_322 (1-2) ;\n[v1_1@0 v1_9@0 v1_21@0 v1_31@0 v1_43@0 v1_53@0 v1_67@0 v1_77@0\nv1_105@0 v1_147@0 v1_196@0 v1_238@0 v1_280@0 v1_322@0];\n[f1_1 f1_9 f1_21 f1_31 f1_43 f1_53 f1_67 f1_77 f1_105 f1_147 f1_196\nf1_238 f1_280 f1_322];"

cat(modelA)
#> f1_1 by v1_1 v2_1 (1-2) ;
#> f1_9 by v1_9 v2_9 (1-2) ;
#> f1_21 by v1_21 v2_21 (1-2) ;
#> f1_31 by v1_31 v2_31 (1-2) ;
#> f1_43 by v1_43 v2_43 (1-2) ;
#> f1_53 by v1_53 v2_53 (1-2) ;
#> f1_67 by v1_67 v2_67 (1-2) ;
#> f1_77 by v1_77 v2_77 (1-2) ;
#> f1_105 by v1_105 v2_105 (1-2) ;
#> f1_147 by v1_147 v2_147 (1-2) ;
#> f1_196 by v1_196 v2_196 (1-2) ;
#> f1_238 by v1_238 v2_238 (1-2) ;
#> f1_280 by v1_280 v2_280 (1-2) ;
#> f1_322 by v1_322 v2_322 (1-2) ;
#> [v1_1@0 v1_9@0 v1_21@0 v1_31@0 v1_43@0 v1_53@0 v1_67@0 v1_77@0
#> v1_105@0 v1_147@0 v1_196@0 v1_238@0 v1_280@0 v1_322@0];
#> [f1_1 f1_9 f1_21 f1_31 f1_43 f1_53 f1_67 f1_77 f1_105 f1_147 f1_196
#> f1_238 f1_280 f1_322];
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you but, this code turned out everything front part was right but the second part looks like this:
[f1_1 f1_9 f1_21 f1_31 f1_43 f1_53 f1_67 f1_77 f1_105 f1_147
f1_196 f1_238 f1_280 f1_322]; [v2_1 v2_9 v2_21 v2_31 v2_43 v2_53 v2_67 v2_77 v2_105 v2_147 v2_196
 v2_238 v2_280 v2_322](3);

Comment: @Ariya I can't read what you have put in the comments. Perhaps update your question to show what's wrong with the output. The above output I got came directly from taking the string you provided and running the code in my answer.

Comment: so the second part is very long one line like this
f1_196 f1_238 f1_280 f1_322]; [v2_1 v2_9 v2_21 v2_31 v2_43 v2_53 v2_67 v2_77 v2_105 v2_147 v2_196

Comment: @AriyaWoodard sorry - if you cut and paste the data you put in the question as `modelA` and use the code I provided, it does what you asked. If you want to edit your question, please do so and let me know. Please don't post extended code in the comments.